# Simple IP address parser in C

Tags: c, strings, parsing, embedded, ip-address

I have written a C function to parse an IP address that should match the regular expression `^\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+` and nothing else.
Additionally all bytes are limited to 0-255.

I tried to catch all invalid inputs, but I am unsure if there are any edge cases I missed or if it could be simplified.

The function is intended to be used in an embedded system. Therefore I don't want to use external libraries (or anything in `stdio.h`) and code size is most important.

I am not really looking for stylistic advice, but rather a functional review.

```
// Returns the number of characters parsed or 0 if not successful
unsigned int StringToIp(uint8_t addr[4], const char* ipSrc, const size_t ipSrcLen) {
    char* ipPtr = ipSrc;
    int16_t current = -1;
    uint8_t addrIdx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ipSrcLen, addrIdx < 4; i++) {
        char c = *ipPtr++;
        if (c == '.') {
            if (current == -1) return 0;  // 2 consecutive dots or dot at beginning
            addr[addrIdx++] = current;
            current = -1;

        } else {
            uint8_t digit = c - '0';
            if (digit >= 10) {
                // Invalid character
                if (addrIdx == 3 && current >= 0) {
                    // Invalid character at the end is treated as the end of the address
                    addr[addrIdx++] = current;
                    ipPtr--;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (current == -1) {
                // first digit of current byte
                current = digit;

            } else {
                // further digits
                current = current * 10 + digit;
                if (current > 255) return 0;  // current byte greater than 255 => invalid
            }
        }
    }

    if (addrIdx == 3 && current >= 0) {
        // write last byte (necessary if at end if string)
        addr[addrIdx++] = current;
    }

    if (addrIdx == 4) {
        // valid IP address
        return ipPtr - ipSrc;

    } else {
        // invalid IP address
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I also wrote the inverse function. Here I am quite sure I got all cases, but the divisions are suboptimal, because the microcontroller has no dedicated divider. Which means extra code for the divisions has to be generated and this bloats the code size and reduces the speed (which is somewhat less important to me).

Is there any why to avoid the divisions?

```
unsigned int IpToString(char ipDst[4*3+3+1], const uint8_t addr[4]) {
    char* ipPtr = ipDst;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        uint8_t current = addr[i];

        uint8_t h = current / 100;
        current -= h * 100;
        uint8_t d = current / 10;
        current -= d * 10;
        uint8_t o = current;

        if (h > 0) *ipPtr++ = '0' + h;
        if (h > 0 || d > 0) *ipPtr++ = '0' + d;
        *ipPtr++ = '0' + o;
        if (i < 3) *ipPtr++ = '.';
    }
    *ipPtr = '\0';
    return ipPtr - ipBuffer;
}
```

Comment: For your second function, since you know the range will be 0-255, why not use a series of `if` statements? Compare with 200, 100, and then a binary search of 10's digits.

Comment: In the future, it is best to provide test cases as part of the code for review so that we can properly review the code.

Comment: Rather than write your own, you could duplicate implementations of `inet_*` from `arpa/inet.h`, for example in [musl](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/network) [`inet_aton.c`](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/network/inet_aton.c) and [`inet_ntoa.c`](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/network/inet_ntoa.c). (Keep in mind to respect musl's license.)

Comment: How should `StringToIp(..., "2.0004.6.8", ...)` function?  (4 digits in a byte)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica At the moment it basically ignores the leading zeros which is fine I think, because it still represents a valid IP.

Comment: @esote These implementations are interesting, but rely on stdio.h and stdlib.h both of which I cannot use.

Comment: @LittleEwok Oh yes, sorry I forgot about that.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. Consider posting a follow-up question with your new code and a link to this question instead.

Comment: @Mast I updated the code because the original contained bugs which are not all addressed in the answers and I did not want to leave it at that in case somebody decides to use this code. Otherwise no working version of my code can be found here. I probably could have written an answer myself but wanted to acknowledge the best given answer by accepting it.

Comment: So post a new question with the improved code, link back from that question to this one and you could even link from this old question towards the new question. Make a little header of sorts on top of your post indicating where the improved code can be found.

Comment: @Mast Although I think you are right that is the standard procedure here, I am not convinced it is the best solution in my case since I don't want or need any further feedback and probably won't even get any. Therefore posting a new question will just lead to an unanswered question for eternity. But if being pedantic is more important than wanting to protect others from buggy code, you are absolutely right. I even intentionally left the original code in the question.

Comment: It has nothing to do with being pedantic. All answerers should review the same version of the code or a convoluted mess will happen. We can't have that, and the only way to prevent it is to disallow code-edits after answers come in. Can't be helped really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Potential bugs

I just spent a few minutes reviewing this, so I'm not sure these are bugs, but you should have a look at them:

1. The comma operator is not the same as `&&`. You have this code:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < ipSrcLen, addrIdx < 4; i++) {
   ```

   but I think you meant to use `&&` instead of `,`. I'm not sure it matters because I'm not sure what the chances are that you will get a mismatch between the string contents and the length, but it's a possible source of error.
2. Incomplete error checking. In the "invalid digit" section of your loop, you have this check:

   ```
   if (addrIdx == 3 && current >= 0) {
   ```

   but you don't do anything if that condition is not true. If `addrIdx` is 0, 1, or 2 you don't handle the bad digit, but instead fall through. I think you need to catch those cases and fail gracefully.

#### `IpToString`

I mentioned this in the comments, but you know the range of values is small. So there's no reason not to replace your divisions with either a series of `if` statements or a lookup table.

Unless you're writing a router or something, I don't expect the lookup table would pay for itself, so the `if` statements seem to be the way to go. Something like this:

```
need_tens_0 = FALSE

// hundreds digit
if number >= 100:
    need_tens_0 = TRUE

    if number >= 200:
        *ptr++ = '2'
        number -= 200
    else:
        *ptr++ = '1'
        number -= 100

// tens digit (binary search)
if number >= 50:
    if number >= 80:
        if number >= 90:
            *ptr++ = '9'
            number -= 90
        else:
            *ptr++ = '8'
            number -= 80

// ... buncha cases omitted ...

else if number >= 10:
else:
    // "6" could be 56 or 106 or 216. Check if we need to insert a padding 0
    if need_tens_0:
        *ptr++ = '0'

// Ones digit
*ptr++ = '0' + number
```

Comment: I think you are right about the comma operator. The compiler output is quite different if I use `&&` instead and does not change if I remove `i < ipSrcLen,`. So it seems `i < ipSrcLen` was being ignored completely. Thank you very much.

Comment: The second point is not true though, because anything else than `addrIdx >= 3` should be treated as an error and return 0, which it does.
I ended up checking the hundreds with if and the tens with division, because that yielded the smallest code size. On a different architecture the binary search may be more efficient but not on mine.

Comment: If you hadn't answered this question, it might have been closed due to Lack of Concrete Context.

Comment: There is no need to replace a division by an integer constant with "more efficient" code, as the compiler will turn the division into a multiplication anyway, at all reasonable optimization levels.

Answer (score 3):

Your compiler should be smart enough to [replace the division by multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41183935). Here's an experiment I did with CLang on x86_64:

```c
#include <inttypes.h>

uint8_t div8_100(uint8_t a) { return a / 100; }
uint8_t div8_10(uint8_t a) { return a / 10; }
```

clang -O3 -Wall -Weverything -S div8.c

```
div8_100:
    movzbl  %cl, %eax
    leal    (%rax,%rax,4), %ecx
    leal    (%rax,%rcx,8), %eax
    shrl    $12, %eax
    retq

div8_10:
    movzbl  %cl, %eax
    imull   $205, %eax, %eax
    shrl    $11, %eax
    retq
```

This is fairly efficient code, and it is not using any exotic opcodes, therefore I expect it to be available on every architecture.

In summary, as long as you divide by integer literals, there is no reason for the compiler to call any external division function.

Comment: I did not know that. Very good to know. That may be the reason why I did not get any benefit from replacing `/ 10` by @Austin Hastings proposed `if`` statements.